# What is the reason for having array-like in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning data structures in JS. What I cannot get is that why array-like concept was created in JS. We have arrays in the language and can perform various actions on them like looping but array-like objects only have length and we cannot loop over them. So, what is the point of having array-like in JS?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by `array-like objects`?

Comment: to access an object property using `[attributeName]` notation for example.

Comment: You can iterate over object, I don't understand this question - Please check the documentation

Comment: Well, that was closed quickly. *saves his answer in case the question is ever reopened*

Comment: @RobG I'd assume that was a typo and she meant `document.getElementsByClassName` et al.

Comment: I guess you mean things like [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)? Some of the newer NodeLists, like that returned by *querySelectorAll* do have a *forEach* method, but they aren't arrays. You can pass them as *this* to other array methods like `Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.foo'), node => node.data.foo)` to get an array of the *data-foo* attributes of node with a class of *foo*.

Comment: for example `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array like object.

Comment: @RobG, you are right. `document.getElementById` returns a single object.

Comment: @NinaScholz—where's that sarcasm emoji when you need it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cannot loop over them"? The classic, traditional iteration over an array is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLike.length; i++) {
    doSomethingWith(arrayLike[i]);
}
```

This assumption is very deeply ingrained; in fact, arrays are mere plain objects in Javascript with the only addition of the `.length` property which has specific behaviour when numeric properties are set on the object and `.push`.

Everything else like `.forEach`, `.map` etc. are convenience additions which, yes, only exist on actual `Array` instances, not array-likes.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, for example here is the code: var d = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
console.log(d.length); In this code getElementsByTagName returns array-like. But why? what if it returns array itself, What I cannot get is that What is the role of arry-like objects in JS why we need array-like objects?

Comment: @qwqwq Javascript itself has "no need" for array-like objects. But for the browser API it makes sense to expose it.

Comment: @qwqwq Well, what Quentin said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57430339/476. Perhaps simplified: there's a difference between the DOM (all those functions and objects the browser exposes to allow you to manipulate what's on the page), and Javascript (the language used to do the manipulation). DOM methods return objects which are as simple as possible; Javascript has elaborate `Array`s with all sorts of extra methods.

Comment: @deceze, can I imagine it like this: array-like objects are returned by e.g getElementsById since array-like objects are related to DOM and not to JS itself and if we want to manipulate array-like objects further with forEach or filter we need to convert them into arrays to access forEach and filter since they both belong to JS itself RIght?

Comment: @qwqwq Yeah, that sounds about right. And the reason why the DOM is not equal to Javascript is that the DOM API is used in many other contexts besides Javascript, and is developed more or less independently of it.

Comment: @deceze, thank you for your kind confirmation but last question I promise, why "arguments" inside function also returns array-like and it is not related to dom? I mean arguments is not connected to DOM but returns array-like object

Comment: @qwqwq My *guess* would be that a) all that stuff was added to `Array` over time, and b) `arguments` is not an array likely due to performance reasons. So, even if it may have started out as basically equivalent to an array, it was never of the `Array` type, and has never gotten the "upgrade" `Array` has received over the years, and likely never will because that would make it slower, which is problematic for something so integral.

Answer (score 2):

Array-like objects are typically implementations of APIs that are defined in a language-agnostic way.

This allows them to be implemented in multiple languages. For instance, `getElementsByTagName` is part of the [DOM specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) and has a [Perl implmentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod#getElementsByTagName).

Since the specification doesn't define the object as having all the properties that a JavaScript array would have, it can't be implemented *as specified* by using an array.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, for example here is the code: var d = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); console.log(d.length); In this code getElementsByTagName returns array-like. But why? what if it returns array itself, What I cannot get is that What is the use of array-like objects in JS why we need array-like objects since we anyways have to convert them into arrays with Array.from?

Comment: @qwqwq — I already explained that in the answer. If it was an array, it wouldn't be what the DOM specification said it should be.